# How can I recover deleted APIs in Azure Portal after accidental deletion in VS Code with Azure API Management extension for version control?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, version-control, apim

I was working on implementing git version controlling for apim policies. I was working in the azure portal tools. I have installed Azure API Management extension for VS Code. I was able to sync it with Azure portal policies, but I accidentally deleted the APIs from the VS Code but all APIs in Azure portal got automatically deleted, is it possible to recover those APIs in the azure portal?

I am a beginner.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/soft-delete#recover-a-soft-deleted-instance

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to recover the deleted API's using API [soft-delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/soft-delete) feature in Azure.

> With API Management soft-delete, you can recover and restore a recently deleted API Management instance. This feature protects against accidental deletion of your API Management instance.

To recover it, you can use the REST API call as shown:

```
Method: PUT
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/<APIMService>?api-version=2021-08-01
```

When an API Management instance is soft-deleted, the service exists in a deleted state and is inaccessible to normal API Management actions.

You can use the API Management Get By Name operation to check whether a soft-deleted API Management instance is still available for restoration. If the APIM instance is available for undeleting, Azure will return a record with the `deletion Date` and `scheduledPurgeDate`.

You can also backup the API management instance while creating, with the help of `Backup-AzApiManagemen` PowerShell command as detailed in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/backup-azapimanagement?view=azps-10.0.0).

[image]